# Curl multi exec POST request to mutliple pages on the same time

Tags: php, curl

Hello i am building web app and i need to send post request using CURL to multiple pages at once, here is my basic example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://mysite1 .com/page1.php'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$myid");
$hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

what i am trying to do is to send the same request to many pages at the same time for example: to mysite1 .com/page1.php,mysite2 .com/page1.php,mysite3 .com/page1.php etc
anyone to help how to use curl multi exec to do this

Comment: you can build an array of sites and use `foreach` loop to do that.

Comment: Why do you asking it again? That was not an accident, that your previos post has closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619992/curl-sending-same-post-request-to-mutliple-pages-oce

Comment: possible duplicate of [understanding php curl\_multi\_exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559157/understanding-php-curl-multi-exec)

Comment: last post you asked it you got an answer: [curl-multi-init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) . you can also look at this (for multi-threading): [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)